# Powershell - replace leading path info

Tags: powershell

I want to remove leading path information using -replace. but no luck.

```
dir "C:\\IT\Tool" -r | % { $_.FullName -replace "C:\\IT\Tool","" }  | out-file c:\temp\FolderList.txt
```

e.g my desired output :

```
\script.txt
\PROD\file.txt
\readme.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably just missed to escape the second path part (\Tool):

```
dir "C:\\IT\Tool" -r | % { $_.FullName -replace "C:\\IT\\Tool","" }  | out-file c:\temp\FolderList.txt
```